# python called from makefile can't find urllib.request

Tags: python, makefile, conda, urllib

This seemed as a typical python2->3 error at first, but I wasn't able to figure out what could be going wrong here. Might have to do with a conflict between `conda` and the makefile.

In my `makefile`, I have a rule:

```
update_stuff:
    python --version
    which python
    python stuff.py
```

which outputs

```
python --version
Python 3.8.3
which python
/Users/username/anaconda3/bin/python
...
```

then in my python script, I have those relevant lines:

```
import urllib
import sys
print(sys.version)
print(sys.executable)
req = urllib.request.Request(URL)
```

which outputs first

```
3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 11:26:31) 
[Clang 10.0.0 ]
/Users/user/anaconda3/bin/python
```

but then gives me an error

```
  File "stuff.py", line 278, in <module>
    req = urllib.request.Request(URL)
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request'
make: *** [update_stuff] Error 1
```

If I just run the file from the command line with `python stuff.py`, it works fine and I cannot see where a python version might be called that doesn't know `urllib`. Running `make SHELL=/bin/bash` changes nothing. Any pointers to how to fix it?

Comment: As an aside, are you using the base/root Conda environment for this?

Comment: yes, I am. I think it worked before, so perhaps it was cause by some update from 3.? to 3.8 when I reinstalled anaconda

Comment: _yes, I am._ Be careful, it can easily lead to some issues. Your best bet is to create a new environment for each project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify import:

```
import urllib.request
```

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request